# A RenderFlex overflowed by 86 pixels on the bottom in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app in flutter and in the portrait mode everything looks fine but when it comes to landscape mode it will be triggered with an error saying `A RenderFlex overflowed by 86 pixels on the bottom`. Below is my all code that I have tried and also I have shared the images, please refer to the same for more clarification.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          brightness: Brightness.dark
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              gradient:LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: [Colors.yellow,Colors.yellow,Colors.orangeAccent,Colors.deepOrange,]
              ),
              // color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
            ),

          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0,left: 50.0),
                child: Text(
                  "SET, MATCH AND CHALLENGE",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0,right: 30.0, top: 30.0),
                child: Text(
                  "A simple, fun, and a creative way to "
                      "set the bespoke challenges with "
                      "either a friend or a group of "
                      "friends anywhere in the world",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 300.0,
                height: 60.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 140.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text("Sign Up",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: pi,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    gradient:LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        end: Alignment.topRight,
                        colors: [Colors.yellow,Colors.yellow,Colors.orangeAccent,Colors.deepOrange,]
                    ),
                    //color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}

class CustomShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double distanceFromWall = 12;
  final double controlPointDistanceFromWall = 5;


  @override
  // TODO: implement dimensions
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => null;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getInnerPath
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getOuterPath
    return getClip(Size(260.0,180.0));
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    // TODO: implement scale
    return null;
  }

  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path clippedPath = new Path();

    clippedPath.lineTo(0, size.height);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(30, size.height + 10, size.width * 0.20, size.height - 50);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(70, size.height - 120, size.width * 0.40, size.height * 0.35);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(180, (size.height - (size.height* 0.6)), size.width - 40 , 32 );
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(250, 0, size.width, 0);
    clippedPath.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    clippedPath.close();
    return clippedPath;
  }
}
```

> **Refer to below image for Portrait Mode**

[image]

> **Refer to below image for Landscape Mode (Where error occurs):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using hardcode margins in a Column widget, that will give you problems in small devices too. You can fix that changing you Column Widget for a ListView Widget, but that is going to give you a Scroll Effect, I think you don't want that. So you can refactor that Column using [Expanded Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo) and a Stack can help in the first part of the Column, try the next:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(
                "SET, MATCH AND CHALLENGE",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Text(
                "A simple, fun, and a creative way to "
                    "set the bespoke challenges with "
                    "either a friend or a group of "
                    "friends anywhere in the world",
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300.0,
          height: 60.0,
          child: RaisedButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.grey,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            child: Text("Sign Up",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```